# adding directory with webpack

Tags: javascript, html, css, webpack

I decided to give webpack a shot and am using a starter kit for a small project. I'm not sure where I am going wrong but I want to add a new directory of files and access them like any other build.In this case it is the folder "particles.js-master". When I add a directory I cannot seem to access anything in the folder. I'm assuming I have to add an output or the like to the webpack config? Any advice would be greatly appreciated, thanks :)

here is my project structure

[image]

webpack:

```
const path = require('path');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const HtmlWebPackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
const { CleanWebpackPlugin } = require('clean-webpack-plugin');
const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require('mini-css-extract-plugin');
const PreloadWebpackPlugin = require('preload-webpack-plugin');
const CssUrlRelativePlugin = require('css-url-relative-plugin');
const glob = require('glob');

const IS_DEV = process.env.NODE_ENV === 'dev';

const config = {
  mode: IS_DEV ? 'development' : 'production',
  devtool: IS_DEV ? 'eval' : 'source-map',
  entry: './src/js/index.js',
  output: {
    filename: 'js/[name].[hash].js',
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
      },
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
         use: [
          {
            loader: MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
            options: {
              hmr: IS_DEV,
             },
          },
           'css-loader',
           'sass-loader',
         ],
       },
       {
        test: /\.(gif|png|jpe?g|svg)$/i,
         use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
           options: {
          limit: 8192,
          name: '[name].[ext]',
          fallback: 'file-loader',
          outputPath: 'public/images',
        },
      },
      {
        loader: 'image-webpack-loader',
        options: {
          mozjpeg: {
            progressive: true,
            quality: 65,
          },
          pngquant: {
            quality: '65-90',
            speed: 4,
          },
          gifsicle: {
            interlaced: false,
          },
          webp: {
            quality: 75,
              },
             },
           },
          ],
         },
        ],
       },
       plugins: [
          new CleanWebpackPlugin(),
          new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
           $: 'jquery',
           jQuery: 'jquery',
            'windows.jQuery': 'jquery',
           }),
      new CopyWebpackPlugin([
       {
         from: './src/public',
         to: 'public',
       },
      ]),
     new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
      filename: IS_DEV ? 'css/[name].css' : 'css/[name].[contenthash].css',
      chunkFilename: 'css/[id].css',
     }),
     new webpack.HashedModuleIdsPlugin(),
    new PreloadWebpackPlugin({
  include: 'initial',
     }),
     new CssUrlRelativePlugin(),
   ],
   devServer: {
     contentBase: path.join(__dirname, 'src'),
   },
    optimization: {
     runtimeChunk: 'single',
     splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          vendor: {
           test: /node_modules/,
           chunks: 'initial',
           name: 'vendor',
           priority: 10,
           enforce: true,
         },
       },
     },
     minimizer: [],
   },
 };

 if (!IS_DEV) {
  const TerserPlugin = require('terser-webpack-plugin');
  const OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin = require('optimize-css-assets-webpack-plugin');

    config.optimization.minimizer.push(
    new TerserPlugin(),
     new OptimizeCSSAssetsPlugin({})
   );
 }

 const files = glob.sync('./src/*.html');

 files.forEach(file => {
     config.plugins.push(
     new HtmlWebPackPlugin({
      filename: path.basename(file),
        template: file,
      favicon: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/public/icon.ico'),
      minify: !IS_DEV,
     })
   );
  });

module.exports = config;
```

Comment: what is inside "particles.js-master" folder? Are you sure that you import files from "particles.js-master" in "src/js/index.js"?

Comment: What do you mean by 'access them like any other build'? As in import files from this directory?

Comment: exactly, i'm used to very simple builds so this is all new to me. When I add a folder to the project. what steps do I need to access them and import them into the project

Comment: So you want to import a file from within `src/particles.js-master` into another file? Which file to you want to import to?

Comment: I just want to access that folder, I must be overthinking this. I would like to access particles.js and also the package.json in that folder

Comment: But what do you mean 'access' them? As in `const ParticleJS = require('./particle-js.master');`, or use `<script src="./particle.js"></script>`

Comment: The simple way to think about Webpack is that it only uses Javascript files as an entry point to creating a build. Webpack doesn't do work on folders. In order for a file to end up in the output bundle, it must be imported by the entry JS file (or by a dependency). In this case, your entry file is `./src/js/index.js`.

Comment: If you want to use particles.js, the easiest way is to use a `require()` or `import` statement in your JS file